# DD a BitLocker/TPM encrypted drive

Tags: 18.04, encryption, ssd, dd, tpm

Is it possible to create a bit identical image of a Windows 10 SSD using an Ubuntu live cd/usb?

If I boot into the laptop with the live/cd/usb, I can't see the drive using fdisk or gparted.

The laptop in question is a Dell Latitute 7490.  The laptop has TPM enabled and the drive is encrypted using BitLocker.  I have tried disabling BitLocker, but still can't see the drive to DD it when using a live cd/usb.

Output from `sudo lsblk`:
[image]

Bitlocker was disabled using the `Turn off BitLocker` option.

Windows 10 was shutdown using both the shift key method and the `shutdown /s /f /t 0` option.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to includ ethe output of `sudo lsblk`

Comment: @vidarlo, output added.

Comment: Please also explain how did you disable BitLocker? Do you have access to the Windows system? Did you simply disable the BitLocker service or did you decrypt the drive itself?

Comment: @linux64kb, Added the details as requested above.

Comment: Even if the drive is encrypted, it should be visible as a drive; would normally be `/dev/sda` and your Ubuntu live drive would be `/dev/sdb`. What kind of drive is it (where Windows is installed)? Is it a 'normal' SSD connected with SATA or m2 interface? -- You must 'see' the drive as a device in order to clone it with `dd` (slower, more risky) or Clonezilla (safer and faster).

Comment: Can you move the drive to another computer and check, it it can be seen as a device `/dev/sdx` there?

Comment: @sudodus, not easily, done, the computer is an ultrabook, so not as convenient as a full tower desktop computer to open and dismantle.

Comment: I see. Well, maybe you can check if there is option in a UEFI/BIOS menu, where you can see and/or activate the internal drive, so that Ubuntu (or any linux system) can see it. -- I have computer, Dell Latitude E7240, that might be similar. It has an m2 SSD card.

Comment: @oshirowanen did you wait until the decryption finished or forced the shutdown before it could finish? `shutdown /s /f /t 0` can simply force Windows to turn off before the decryption could finish.

Answer (score 5):

There is a driver called **dislocker** for mounting BitLocker partition with FUSE

Available in Ubuntu repositories since 18.04:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=dislocker

```
sudo apt install dislocker
```

See more:
https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker

Comment: So using dislocker, I should be able to mount the drive, and then list it using fdisk and even DD it to create a backup of the entire drive?

Comment: You will be able to mount the crypted volumes -  Of course you need the key file (`.bek`) or the recovery password. - Once installed, see the documentation `man dislocker`